# Setup Kubernetes with LB & ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to configure a single node kubernetes clustor with a load balancer and ingress but I cant reach it from my external IP. Also if I try to curl/wget the internal IP of the LB it doesen't work. I can propperly curl/wget the service itself. Can anyone help me?

**configuration**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: MY_DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: apple-service
            servicePort: 5678
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443

  externalIPs:
    - XX.XX.XX.XX


---

kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-app
  labels:
    app: apple
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apple-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=apple"

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apple
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
```

**kubectl get all**

```
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/apple-app   1/1     Running   0          12m

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
service/apple-service   ClusterIP      10.108.8.152    <none>            5678/TCP                     12m
service/ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.111.230.95   XX.XX.XX.XX  80:30338/TCP,443:31035/TCP   10m
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>            443/TCP                      6d
```

**kubectl get ingress**

```
NAME           HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
test-ingress   *                 80      6d
```

**curl 10.107.97.101:5678**

```
apple
```

**curl XX.XX.XX.XX:80 (external ip)|localhost:80|MY_DOMAIN:80**

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to XX.XX.XX.XX port 80: Connection refused
```

**installation**

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

mkdir $HOME/.kube -p
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/admin.conf
echo "export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/admin.conf" | tee -a ~/.bashrc


# flanel
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.9.1/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml

# untained master to use as container host
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-


# Install helm - for lets encrypt
sudo snap install helm --classic
PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin

# enable helm
helm init
helm install --name cert-manager -f cert-manager-values.yaml --namespace=default stable/cert-manager --set rbac.create=false
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io

# create letsencrypt 
kubectl create namespace cert-manager
kubectl label namespace cert-manager certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation=true
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/release-0.8/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml
```

Comment: Where does `externalIP` is coming from? Did you created your external `LoadBalancer` manually?

Comment: The external IP is the public IP of my Server

Comment: Can try to `curl <ExternalIP>:30338` and let us know if this is working? If you are running in cloud remember to allow traffic to that port on firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Fabi your service name in test-ingress spec should be

> serviceName: apple-service

and also remove

> externalTrafficPolicy: Local

from your ingress-nginx service spec.

Edit your ingress spec to this:

> `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
>   kind: Ingress
>   metadata:
>     name: test-ingress
>   spec:
>     rules:
>     - host: *
>       http:
>         paths:
>         - path: /*
>           backend:
>             serviceName: apple-service
>             servicePort: 5678`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the specs but it is still the same behavior

Comment: can you check the security group

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Is this k8s cluster running in cloud or onprem?

Comment: I Installed it natively on ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server

Comment: can you check the ingress spec which I have edited above

Comment: I had to change host: * to host MY_DOMAIN but it is still the same behaviour. Ill add my installation porccess above

Comment: can you change the clusterType of apple-service to LoadBalancer from ClusterIP. for narrowing down the issue.

Comment: I have done that but it havent change somenting.
**kubectl get all**
```
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/apple-app   1/1     Running   0          39m

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
service/apple-service   LoadBalancer   10.97.114.134    <pending>         5678:32351/TCP               39m
service/ingress-nginx   LoadBalancer   10.107.214.154   XX.XX.XX.XX   80:30647/TCP,443:32502/TCP   39m

```

Comment: U can ignore the above service since you are using nginx ingress controller. Can you try hitting curl localhost:80/apple . Also revert back service from LoadBalancer to  clusterIP and then change the path as / instead of /* in the ingress spec.

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, so I update the specs and results above. It doesent work for me yet